# How to add a link in php

Tags: php, html, sql, database

Hi I'm kind of new to the site and to php. I am trying to make a code which tells hello to a user if logged in or displays the Register/Login form if the user is logged out. Following is the code for it :

```
<?php       if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
        {echo   " <a href=register.php >Register </a> Or <a href=login.php>Login</a>" ;         
        }
        else{
        Hello htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); you currently have $_SESSION['user']['point']; points !
        }. ?>
```

But it gives me an error :

```
                                   PHP Error Message

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a3897717/public_html/index1.php on line 63
```

And the 63rd line is this one :

```
Hello htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); you currently have $_SESSION['user']['point']; points !
```

Please if anyone can help me, Please help !
Thanks in advance ! This not the duplicate i just want someone to tell me where i am wrong and correct that mistake .

Answer (score 0):

You're messing up with the *concatenation*.

Change this:

```
echo "<a href=register.php >Register </a> Or <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<a href='register.php'>Register </a> Or <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
```

and this:

```
Hello htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); you currently have $_SESSION['user']['point']; points !
```

to this:

```
echo "Hello " . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "you currently have " . $_SESSION['user']['point'] . "points!";
```

**EDIT:**

Since I could not find a online PHP/HTML compiler, to show that the above code works I have attached a picture:

[image]

> Note: It is obvious that the error is shown as the sessions are not
>   defined and neither was the core problem of this question.

Comment: No, It Dint Help . Now it started givng me error on line 60 too ! I had my problem on line 63 before ... line 60 was prefectly fine.

Comment: @TheGamingGuy What is on line 60? and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Line 60 :echo "<a href='register.php' >Register </a> Or <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
 and error i got :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/a3897717/public_html/index1.php on line 60

Comment: @TheGamingGuy check my edit.

Comment: Did the same as you same but it still does not show the points : <br> [link]http://teamlegit.site11.com/test.png

Comment: @TheGamingGuy try to `echo` your sessions and see if you have any value in it

Answer (score 0):

You missed a echo before your output string:

```
echo "Hello " . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
echo "you currently have " . $_SESSION['user']['point'];
echo "points !";
```

Comment: It Accepted line 63 now and executed  the code but it did not display my points or said hello to me when i logged in.